# Place checkbox input value into checkbox itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I would like to place the value of my checkbox inside of the checkbox itself, instead of being to the side of the checkbox.

I think this may give an overall more pleasing visual than simple text next to a checkbox.

I'm only able to use jQuery 1.3.2 for this website (SaaS restriction) as well, so just a heads up.

Here is the current checkbox layout. I'd like to place the values inside of the checkboxes

[image: Picture #1]

And this is what I would like for it to look like:

[image: Picture #2]

So, what I'm wondering, how can I do this, and is it with CSS or JS? Or a combination of both?

My current HTML looks like the following:

```
<ul class="linkList" id="binValue-6"><li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="10" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=10&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
10
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="12" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=12&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
12
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="12M" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=12M&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
12M
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="14" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=14&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
14
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="16" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=16&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
16
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="18M" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=18M&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
18M
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="24" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=24&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
24
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="24M" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=24M&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
24M
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="2T" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=2T&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
2T
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="3T" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=3T&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
3T
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="4" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=4&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
4
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="4T" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=4T&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
4T
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="5" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=5&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
5
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="6" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
6
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="6X" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=6X&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
6X
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="7" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=7&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
7
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="8" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=8&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
8
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="9M" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=9M&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
9M
</a>
</li>
<li class="binValue">
<input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">    <input name="binValue" value="One Size" type="hidden">        <a href=".com/b/5819597011?field_size_name=One+Size&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchNodeID=5819597011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
<input type="checkbox">   
One Size
</a>
</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean when you click checkbox? And the value is the text, next to the checkbox?

Comment: I would like to make this http://i.imgur.com/DksAwlU.png look like this instead: http://i.imgur.com/n3UQjNX.png

Comment: From your images - it's buttons with text, not checkboxes

Comment: @Justinas Correct, however, I would like to make it look like that. I am unable to change the HTML due to how the SaaS environment works, but I am sure that someone would be able to assist with some clever CSS or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Below CSS should put you right track

```
.cb-toolbar input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none; 
}

.cb-toolbar label {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:4px 11px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
}

.cb-toolbar input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { 
    background-color:#bbb;
}
```

Here is html markup.

```
<div class="cb-toolbar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
    <label for="checkbox1">10</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="radios"value="false">
    <label for="checkbox2">12</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="radios" value="true">
    <label for="checkbox3">12M</label> 
</div>
```

**[Live Demo with JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h6rqaLq5/1/)**

Comment: @janderson133787 Accept this answer if it answers your question.